# How can I share some object over all clients?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

For caching's sakes I need to share single object instance over clients connected to the server (Tomcat 7). How can I do that?

I'm using spring framework, so the first thought that popped into my head was to store it as a spring bean with an [application scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes) and modify it if needed.

Is that a good approach to do that?

Comment: Yes, storing object which has to be shared in Application Scope is good idea.

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD BTW, do you personally do that for caching? I mean we will have to synchronize the methods if needed, right?